# Modular Representation in the semi-simple case

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $K$ is a field of characteristic $0$ such that $K=\operatorname{Frac} A$ where $A$ is a local PID. $p=\langle \pi \rangle $ is the maximal ideal of $A$ and $k=A/p$ is the residue field. Assume that $K$ is large enough for $G$ in the sense that $$\operatorname{Irr}_K(G)\rightarrow \operatorname{Irr}_\bar K (G) $$ $$V\mapsto \bar K[G]\otimes_{K[G]}V$$ is a bijection. 
 Further assume that $|G|\neq 0$ in $k$. 
 I want to show the following result. 
 
  **With the assumptions as above, let $V$ be a simple $K[G]$-module. Then any $\pi$-modular reduction $V\mod \pi$ is a simple $k[G]$-module. In particular $k$ is also large enough for $G$. Moreover we have a natural bijection $$\operatorname{Sim}(K[G])\cong \operatorname{Sim}(k[G])$$ preserving dimension.**   
Here's what I have done so far.

I know that for each $V\in \operatorname{Irr}_K(G)$, there is a central idempotent $e_V\in A[G]\subset K[G]$ which acts as $\operatorname{id}$ on $V$ and as $0$ on $W\ncong V$ for $W\in \operatorname{Irr}_K(G)$. Also we have the equation $$1=\sum_{V\in \operatorname{Irr}_K(G)}e_V$$ Since the equation holds in $A[G]$, reducing $\mod p$, we get $$1=\sum_{V\in \operatorname{Irr}_K(G)}\bar e_V\text{ in }k[G]$$ Let $M_V$ be a complete $G$-stable $A$ lattice of $V$. Since $e_V$ acts as identity on $V$, $\bar e_V$ acts as identity on $M_V/ pM_V$ and hence $\bar e_V\neq 0$ in $k[G]$ Also since $e_W$ acts as $0$ on $M_V$, $\bar e_W$ acts as $0$ on $M_V/pM_V$. Thus we get $| \operatorname{Irr}_K(G)|=:r$ many central idempotents in $k[G]$.             
 If $$K[G]=\bigoplus_{i=1}^rV_i^{\oplus d_i}$$ as $K[G]$-modules, then we have $$M=\bigoplus_{i=1}^r{M_{V_i}}^{\oplus d_i}$$ is a $G$-stable free $A$-module of rank $|G|$. Hence $$M/pM=\bigoplus_{i=1}^r{M_{V_i}/pM_{V_i}}^{\oplus d_i}$$ is a $k$ vector space of rank $|G|$. I am unsure as to how to proceed after this. Any help will be appreciated. Any reference for the above result will also be most welcome.

**Edit:** I know $M$ and $A[G]$ are both complete $G$-stable $A$-lattices in $K[G]$. So in particular both $k[G]$ and $M/pM$ have the same composition factors in their Jordan-Holder series as $k[G]$-modules. Since $k[G]$ is semi-simple, each will be a direct sum of the composition factors. 
Let $V$ be a simple $K[G]$-module which is a sub-module of $K[G]$. Say $v_1,v_2,\dots v_d$ be a basis of $V$ as a $K$ vector space. Then after possibly clearing the denominators, one can assume that $\{v_1,\dots,v_d \}\subset A[G]$. If $M_V$ be the $A[G]$ module generated by $\{v_1,\dots,v_d \}$, then it is a complete $G$-stable $A$-lattice of $V$ which is contained in $A[G]$.   
 If we do this construction for every $V_i$, then we can assume $M\subset A[G]$. I don't know if this helps.

Comment: Must the characteristic of $k$ divide $|G|$? Also, you may be interested in Part 3 of Serre's *Linear Representations of Finite Groups*, which I think considers representations over local fields vs over their residue fields.

Comment: No the assumption is that $\operatorname{char}k \nmid  |G|$.